# Nvidia X Server - Overclocking Pascal Based Video Card

Tags: nvidia, graphics, overclocking

I am currently experimenting with overclocking my graphics card in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I recently learned about Coolbits, and enabled bits 2 and 3 (Option "Coolbits" "12") in my xorg.conf file.  After a reboot, this enabled the relevant options: manual fan speed and overclocking via the Powermizer tab.  Both settings are now visible in their respective sections, but for some reason I am not seeing the checkbox for "Enable Performance Level Editing" under the Editable Performance Levels section in Powermizer.  I can, however, type values into the Graphics Clock Offset and Memory Transfer Rate Offset fields, but when pressing enter the values are not applied.

I'm currently using the latest proprietary Nvidia Driver (375.66), and my graphics card is an Asus Nvidia GTX 1080 TI Strix OC Edition.

I suppose my questions are:

1.) Does Coolbits work with Pascal based video cards yet?  And if so are there a certain cards that are/aren't supported at the moment?

2.) Is there a step I missed to fully enable the Editbale Performance Levels section in Powermizer?

Comment: The latest driver is 384.59. The driver you're using isn't listed for 10 series GPUs. Try to update your drivers and try again. https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers

Answer (score 0):

I got my answers from https://gist.github.com/bsodmike/369f8a202c5a5c97cfbd481264d549e9:

command line for each card:

```
nvidia-setttings -c :0 -a '[gpu:0]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=1300'
nvidia-settings -c :0 -a '[gpu:0]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=100'
```

Comment: Do these commands persist, or do they need to be reapplied at every boot?